# Views in my recyclerView is not in center on all phones?

Tags: android, xml

I have a very irritating problem with my views. As you see on a galaxy S7 my views is perfectly in center, but on a galaxy S4 mini they are placed down at the bottom!

I have tried to change alot in XML without any succses. I think it may be of the way I designet the whole thing with recyclerview, tabviews etc.

The following dont work either:

```
layout_InParent, Gravity:Center, layout_centerVertical
```

[image]

**Imagebutton item for the recyclerview.    *item_colorbutton.xml:***

```
android:id="@+id/colorbutton"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_margin="15dp"
android:background="@drawable/bbtn">
```

**BACKGROUND tabfragement.    *tab_fragment_1.xml*:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/rvColors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**This is the viewpager for the different tabs: *BACKGROUND, FONT, TEXT STYLE***

```
    <org.m.muddzboy.QuoteCreator.ViewPager.NonSwipeableViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="51pt"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#517293" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent view seems to be limited height... and your recyclerview wraps children, plus it has top margin of 10dp. So you have 10dp, then 15dp + 15dp top and bottom margin of child view (you set general margin of 15dp, so all sides), plus 48dp height of child view. Seems like on low density devices that is not enough for your view which contains recyclerview. So it follows the rules and pushes your views down. It cannot break set margin. It has to set them as you requested.

In situations like this it's better to have dimensions for different device configurations. And if it's too complex, setting relative dimensions programmatically based on measured height of containing view.

Comment: Allright, so I think programmatically based on the height sounds as the best solution, but which views should I programmatically calculate the heights of? can you give me an example

Comment: The item view of your recyclerview. I would set their height and margins relatively to measured height of container. You can pass it to adapter as constructor parameters. Make it let's say... the height 3/4 of total height and the rest setup to be margins and divide by 2 of course.

Comment: I have once had similar problem with note 5 device. The dpi there is weird. And I had grid view with automatic size columns.  Would create enormous gaps on note. So I had to calculate cell width based on view width programmatically. A little hassle,  but worth it. Looks good on all devices.

Comment: I have tried to get the view containers size by saying this: `viewPager.getHeight()` which gives me the height in pixels. On the S7 its 411 and on the S4 mini it is 111...

Comment: The actual number is irrelevant, you will be using it to calculate actual height of your child views. But it does explain alot about your image 

Comment: Hi again. Can you please help with some code, I have no clue about where to start og what to do exactly. It's a very frustrating problem!